# PHP looping over object manipulate output based on object length

Tags: php, loops, object, foreach

I have a PHP object that I am looping over, I know 2 things are definate with this object, I will never need to loop more than 12 times (1-12) and I will also always have to loop at least  once.

My problem comes when the object is longer than 6 items, as if it is longer than 6 items I need to split the results into 2 `<ol>` and for the live of me I cannot figure out a nice way to do this?

Here is my attempt,

```
<?php $count =  1; ?>
    <?php if(is_object($active_projects)) : ?>
        <div class="col_1">
            <?php if($count < 2) : ?>
                <strong>Active projects</strong> <a href="/projects" class="view">View All</a>
            <?php endif; ?>
               <ol <?php echo ($count > 1 ? " class='no-header'" : ""); ?>>
                   <?php foreach($active_projects as $project) : ?>
                       <li><a href=""><?php echo $project->project_name; ?></a></li>
                       <?php $count ++; ?>
                       <?php endforeach; ?>
               </ol>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Now my attempt displays all the results in one list, how can if there are more than 6 items in the object, split the loop in 2 so that I output 2 `<div class="col_1">` with a list of 6 items in each?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
//create an object with 12 items
$obj = new stdClass();
for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
    $project = "project_$i";
    $obj->{$project} = new stdClass();
    $obj->{$project}->name = "Project $i";
}

function wrapInLi($projectName)
{
    return "<li>$projectName</li>\n";
}

function wrapInOl($arrayOfLi)
{
    $returnString = "<ol>\n";
    foreach ($arrayOfLi as $li)
    {
        $returnString .= $li;
    }
    return $returnString . "</ol>\n";
}

/*
 * The classname is adjustable, just in case
 */
function wrapInDiv($ol, $class)
{
    return "<div class='$class'>\n$ol</div>\n";
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $arrayOfLi = array();
        foreach($obj as $project)
        {
            //fill an array with list-items
            $arrayOfLi[] = wrapInLi($project->name);

            //six list-items? wrap it
            if(count($arrayOfLi) === 6)
            {
                //wrap in unordered list
                $ol = wrapInOl($arrayOfLi);
                //wrap in div and echo
                echo wrapInDiv($ol, 'col_1');
                //reset array
                $arrayOfLi = array();
            }
        }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```